# Non exhaustive pattern error when decoding Huffman tree?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, huffman-code

I'm trying to turn a Huffman tree and a stream of bits into a list of characters plus a boolean indicating whether or not the output consumed all the input bits. Here's an example:

```
decode xyz_code [True,False,True,True,True,False,False,True] = 
("yzyx",False)
```

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't work. What's going wrong? Help!

```
data BTree a = Leaf a | Fork (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

decode :: BTree a -> [Bool] -> ([a], Bool)
decode _ [] = ([],True)
decode (Leaf v) [bs] = ([v], bs)
decode (Fork left right) (b:bs)
   | b         = decode right bs
   | otherwise = decode left bs
```

Comment: The compiler thinks `decode (Leaf v) [bs]` doesn’t cover lists of length ≥ 2.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: In general, if it’s never supposed to happen, either define it as an error or rearrange your types so it can never exist.

Comment: could you be more specific? i don't understand what's wrong and what i should be changing

Answer (score 1):

The title seems to indicate that you get a warning about an incomplete pattern-match. Consider it:

```
58567334.hs:6:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `decode': Patterns not matched: (Leaf _) (_:_:_)
  |
6 | decode _ [] = ([],True)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

It says that the pattern that involves any `Leaf` with a list of Booleans longer than two isn't covered.

The first pattern that matches on `[]` matches the empty list.

The next pattern that matches on `[bs]` matches on a list with *a single element* called `bs`. This is a common mistake.

You probably want this pattern instead:

```
decode (Leaf v) bs = -- ...
```

where `bs` is a `[Bool]` value (i.e. a list of Boolean values).

Now you have to figure out how to aggregate that list of Boolean values to a single `Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

- `_ []` covers empty lists
- `(Fork left right) (b:bs)` covers non-empty lists for `Fork`s
- `(Leaf v) [bs]` covers lists of length 1 for `Leaf`s

So what’s missing that the compiler is warning you about? Lists of length > 1 for `Leaf`s. You need to define this case as something. If reaching that state isn’t logically valid, an error is okay:

```
data BTree a = Leaf a | Fork (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

decode :: BTree a -> [Bool] -> ([a], Bool)
decode _ [] = ([], True)
decode (Leaf v) [bs] = ([v], bs)
decode (Leaf v) _ = error "Too much code left at leaf"
decode (Fork left right) (b:bs)
   | b         = decode right bs
   | otherwise = decode left bs
```